# How to filter in particular records in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to do a search but problem is I can search in whole table not only in those records I fetched in first place!

```
public function getAllReceivedNotifies($request){

    $notifies = Notify::with('sender','sender.role')
                ->where('receiver_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

    if ($request->has('q')) {
        $notifies->where('reason', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->get('q') . "%");
        $notifies->orWhere('comment', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->get('q') . "%");
        $notifies->orWhere('created_at', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->get('q') . "%");
    }
    return $notifies->paginate();
}
```

Comment: your query is look like where x and y or z or t but what you want is where a and (b or c or d) . ?

Comment: You should edit your question and clarify what's wrong with the code you posted. i'm guessing the error so i will post an answer

Comment: I want:  if that text I wrote in search input is like 'reason' or 'comment' or 'created_at'

Comment: @N69S I'm not getting any error here. I'm just getting wrong results and my code looks fine. Maybe someone will help me in this case. Thanks

Comment: @GenFa take a look at my answer, chages `receiver & reason || comment ||created_at` to  `receiver & (reason || comment ||created_at)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put the three string search in parenthesis, you do that by grouping them into `where()` in eloquent

```
public function getAllReceivedNotifies($request){

    $notifies = Notify::with('sender','sender.role')
            ->where('receiver_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

    if ($request->has('q')) {
        $notifies->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('reason', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->get('q') . "%");
            $query->orWhere('comment', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->get('q') . "%");
            $query->orWhere('created_at', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->get('q') . "%");
        });
    }
    return $notifies->paginate();
}
```